# In a asp .net web site is it possible to create instance of code behind from master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, migration

I have a ASP .Net web application and I am converting it into a ASP .net web site and during the conversion I am getting an error while accessing code behind of a page from master page.

```
               if (Master.Page is ProjectRequestss)
                {
                    ProjectRequestss pr = (ProjectRequestss)Master.Page;
                    Project_ID = Convert.ToString(pr.Project_ID);
                    Request_Type_ID = Convert.ToString(pr.Request_Type_ID);
                    LLB_Proj_Detail_ID = Convert.ToString(pr.LB_Proj_Detail_ID);
                    JobID = Convert.ToString(pr.JobID);
                }
```

This used to work fine in ASP .net web application but it is not working in ASP .net web site. Any idea about doing the same in web site.

1. Error    11  The type or namespace name 'ProjectRequestss' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\My Work\Application\Web\dadadsfsadfdr module seperation\dadadsfsadfd\dadadsfsadfd.WebUIWebsite\LandBase\dadadsfsadfd.master.cs   41  36  D:...\dadadsfsadfd.WebUIWebsite\
2. Error    12  The type or namespace name 'ProjectRequestss' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\My Work\Application\Web\dadadsfsadfd module seperation\dadadsfsadfd\dadadsfsadfd.WebUIWebsite\LandBase\dadadsfsadfd.master.cs    43  21  D:...\dadadsfsadfd.WebUIWebsite\
3. Error    13  The type or namespace name 'ProjectRequestss' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\My Work\Application\Web\ISO Tracker module seperation\dadadsfsadfd\dadadsfsadfd.WebUIWebsite\LandBase\dadadsfsadfd.master.cs 43  42  D:...\dadadsfsadfd.WebUIWebsite\

   public partial class ProjectRequestss : abcdfdfd_Page
   {
       #region Properties

   ```
   private bool Is_Update
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["Is_Update"] == null || ViewState["Is_Update"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return false;
           else
               return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["Is_Update"].ToString());
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["Is_Update"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   public int Project_ID
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["Project_ID"] == null || ViewState["Project_ID"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return -1;
           else
               return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Project_ID"]);
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["Project_ID"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   public int Request_Type_ID
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["Request_Type_ID"] == null || ViewState["Request_Type_ID"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return -1;
           else
               return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Request_Type_ID"]);
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["Request_Type_ID"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   public int LB_Proj_Detail_ID
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["LB_Proj_Detail_ID"] == null || ViewState["LB_Proj_Detail_ID"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return -1;
           else
               return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["LB_Proj_Detail_ID"]);
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["LB_Proj_Detail_ID"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   public int JobID
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["JobID"] == null || ViewState["JobID"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return -1;
           else
               return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["JobID"]);
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["JobID"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   public string JTS_ID
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["JTS_ID"] == null || ViewState["JTS_ID"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return "-1";
           else
               return Convert.ToString(ViewState["JTS_ID"]);
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["JTS_ID"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   public string Job_Status_ID
   {
       get
       {
           if (ViewState["Job_Status_ID"] == null || ViewState["Job_Status_ID"].ToString() == string.Empty)
               return "-1";
           else
               return Convert.ToString(ViewState["Job_Status_ID"]);
       }
       set
       {
           ViewState["Job_Status_ID"] = value.ToString();
       }
   }

   #endregion
   ```

   }

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: i have updated the question with error

Comment: you need to have ProjectRequests class.

Comment: yes added ProjectRequests class